# tabLayout.setOnTabSelectedListener on swiping not called

Tags: android, android-viewpager, android-tablayout

I am trying to highlight tab icon when viewPager is selected or swiped. For this I am using `'tabLayout.setOnTabSelectedListener()'`. But it doesn't highlight when I swipe tab, but when I press tab selected all work perfect and tab gets highlighted. May be it's related with gradle version. I am using `'classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.0''` . This is activity :

```
 private int[] tabIcons = {
        R.drawable.tab_icon_home,
        R.drawable.tab_icon_cart2,
        R.drawable.tab_icon_aksia,
        R.drawable.tab_icon_menu
};
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_icon_tabs);

    toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    toolbar.setTitleTextColor(Color.WHITE);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    frameLayout = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.frameLayout);

    adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
    viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
    viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
    viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(pageChangeListener);
    viewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(10);
    tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
    tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
    setupTabIcons();

}


private OnPageChangeListener pageChangeListener = new OnPageChangeListener() {

    int currentPosition = 0;

    @Override
    public void onPageSelected(int newPosition) {

            FragmentLifecycle fragmentToHide = (FragmentLifecycle) adapter.getItem(currentPosition);
            fragmentToHide.onPauseFragment();

            FragmentLifecycle fragmentToShow = (FragmentLifecycle) adapter.getItem(newPosition);
            fragmentToShow.onResumeFragment();

            currentPosition = newPosition;
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

    }

    @Override
    public void onPageScrolled(int arg0, float arg1, int arg2) {

    }

    public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int arg0) { }
};

private void setupTabIcons() {


    tabLayout.getTabAt(0).setIcon(tabIcons[0]);
    tabLayout.getTabAt(1).setIcon(tabIcons[1]);
    tabLayout.getTabAt(2).setIcon(tabIcons[2]);
    tabLayout.getTabAt(3).setIcon(tabIcons[3]);

    tabLayout.getTabAt(0).getIcon().setColorFilter(Color.WHITE, PorterDuff.Mode.MULTIPLY);
    tabLayout.getTabAt(1).getIcon().setColorFilter(Color.parseColor("#81C784"), PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN);
    tabLayout.getTabAt(2).getIcon().setColorFilter(Color.parseColor("#81C784"), PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN);
    tabLayout.getTabAt(3).getIcon().setColorFilter(Color.parseColor("#81C784"), PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN);



    tabLayout.setOnTabSelectedListener( new TabLayout.ViewPagerOnTabSelectedListener(viewPager) {
        @Override
        public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
            super.onTabSelected(tab);

                tab.getIcon().setColorFilter(Color.WHITE, PorterDuff.Mode.MULTIPLY);


        }

        @Override
        public void onTabUnselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
            super.onTabUnselected(tab);

            tab.getIcon().setColorFilter(Color.parseColor("#81C784"), PorterDuff.Mode.MULTIPLY);
        }

        @Override
        public void onTabReselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
            super.onTabReselected(tab);

        }
    });


}
```

Comment: write your code for tab highlight in onPageSelected let me know if it wont work

Comment: @Nisarg it's work in onPageSelected(), but how can I implement onPageUnSelected()?

Comment: you dont need to implement for unselect just use that position and code accordingly

Comment: @Nisarg Ok, if I don't use UnSelect unselected tab stay  highlight

Comment: hope you got solution now?

Comment: @Nisarg no I didn't get solution. unselected tab stay highlight, I need to selected tab highlight and unselected tab other color

Comment: try [This](https://github.com/DevLight-Mobile-Agency/NavigationTabStrip) its very easy to use.with this you can overcome with your current problem

Answer (score 1):

I found solution,in gradle I used

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.0.0' }
```

And I change from 23.0.0 to 23.0.1 in both appcompat-v7 and design. Now all work for me.

Comment: pardon me for guided you in different way, didn't know this, new to know :)

Answer (score 0):

When you call `setupWithViewPager`, this will internally call `setOnTabSelectedListener(new ViewPagerOnTabSelectedListener(viewPager));`, overriding your `OnTabSelectedListener`.

you have implemented `TabLayout.ViewPagerOnTabSelectedListener`, and then overridden `onTabSelected()` and call `setOnTabSelectedListener()` after `setupWithViewPager()`:

This is correct and it is working fine when tab clicked, 
You are saying that when you scroll the page, it is not working. Have a look at your `onPageSelected()` of `OnPageChangeListener()`. Because this method gets called as and when particular Page selected.

Answer (score 0):

Try this way...

```
tabLayout = ((TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs));
adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new TabLayout.TabLayoutOnPageChangeListener(
                        tabLayout));
tabLayout.setOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener() {
            public void onTabReselected(TabLayout.Tab paramAnonymousTab) {
            }

            public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab paramAnonymousTab) {
                viewPager.setCurrentItem(paramAnonymousTab.getPosition());
                tab.getIcon().setColorFilter(Color.WHITE, PorterDuff.Mode.MULTIPLY);
            }

            public void onTabUnselected(TabLayout.Tab paramAnonymousTab) {
                tab.getIcon().setColorFilter(Color.parseColor("#81C784"), PorterDuff.Mode.MULTIPLY);
            }
});

tabLayout.getTabAt(0).setIcon(tabIcons[0]);
tabLayout.getTabAt(1).setIcon(tabIcons[1]);
tabLayout.getTabAt(2).setIcon(tabIcons[2]);
tabLayout.getTabAt(3).setIcon(tabIcons[3]);

tabLayout.getTabAt(0).getIcon().setColorFilter(Color.WHITE, PorterDuff.Mode.MULTIPLY);
tabLayout.getTabAt(1).getIcon().setColorFilter(Color.parseColor("#81C784"), PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN);
tabLayout.getTabAt(2).getIcon().setColorFilter(Color.parseColor("#81C784"), PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN);
tabLayout.getTabAt(3).getIcon().setColorFilter(Color.parseColor("#81C784"), PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN);

viewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(4);
```

Happy coding.

Comment: what problem you are facing in that?

Comment: I did as you said but nothing happened. The problem remains

Comment: setOnTabSelectedListener is deprecated, use addOnTabSelectedListener instead